# Router potentially blocking single device

Tags: linux, networking, router

I have a `Vox3.0v` Vodafone Router. It's been seemingly working fine until I tried using a raspberry pi on the network. I can SSH into the pi, but I can't seem to access any web servers from it. In particular, I can't `apt-get update` at all with this being the result

```
sudo apt update -y
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Could not connect to 145.239.85.58:9300 (145.239.85.58), connection timed out
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
  Could not connect to 145.239.85.58:9300 (145.239.85.58), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Could not connect to 145.239.85.58:9300 (145.239.85.58), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Could not connect to 145.239.85.58:9300 (145.239.85.58), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Debugging with `curl` and `wget`, I found that I had to specify `https` in the url for it to work (i.e. `google.com` times out whilst `https://google.com` works fine).

The DNS server is set to `8.8.8.8` in the router, and on the local device.

`dig` doesn't provide much more details either

```
 dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.33-Raspbian <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 65524
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             175     IN      A       142.250.187.206

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 10 08:48:05 BST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

However, as soon as I add my desktop using `privoxy` as a proxy server, it works fine.  This is why I'm led to believe it's the router having an issue with the pi:

```
sudo apt update -y
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

```
http_proxy="http://192.168.1.19:8118" curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Is there any other debugging I could do to narrow this issue down?

====

Edit: `tcpdump -i any not port 22`, then copy/pasted a TCP stream from `wget google.com` which finishes with a `RST`... doing the same with `wget https://google.com` completes successfully still.

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
137 73.203180   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 80  59346 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=1623844333 TSecr=0 WS=128
138 73.204775   142.250.200.46  192.168.1.192   TCP 80  80 → 59346 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=1140247999 TSecr=1623844333 WS=64
139 73.204826   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 72  59346 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1623844335 TSecr=1140247999
140 73.205189   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  HTTP    195 GET / HTTP/1.1 
141 73.423754   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 195 [TCP Retransmission] 59346 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=123 TSval=1623844554 TSecr=1140247999
142 73.643749   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 195 [TCP Retransmission] 59346 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=123 TSval=1623844774 TSecr=1140247999
143 74.073747   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 195 [TCP Retransmission] 59346 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=123 TSval=1623845204 TSecr=1140247999
144 74.204798   142.250.200.46  192.168.1.192   TCP 80  [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 59346 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=1140248999 TSecr=1623845204 WS=64
145 74.204839   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 72  [TCP Dup ACK 139#1] 59346 → 80 [ACK] Seq=124 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1623845335 TSecr=1140247999
146 74.983732   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 195 [TCP Retransmission] 59346 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=123 TSval=1623846114 TSecr=1140247999
147 76.204841   142.250.200.46  192.168.1.192   TCP 80  [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 59346 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=1140250999 TSecr=1623846114 WS=64
148 76.204881   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 72  [TCP Dup ACK 139#2] 59346 → 80 [ACK] Seq=124 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1623847335 TSecr=1140247999
149 76.743729   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 195 [TCP Retransmission] 59346 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=123 TSval=1623847874 TSecr=1140247999
155 80.183741   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 195 [TCP Retransmission] 59346 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=123 TSval=1623851314 TSecr=1140247999
156 80.204722   142.250.200.46  192.168.1.192   TCP 80  [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 59346 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=1140254999 TSecr=1623851314 WS=64
157 80.204764   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 72  [TCP Dup ACK 139#3] 59346 → 80 [ACK] Seq=124 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1623851335 TSecr=1140247999
159 87.553743   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 195 [TCP Retransmission] 59346 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=123 TSval=1623858684 TSecr=1140247999
160 88.204963   142.250.200.46  192.168.1.192   TCP 80  [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 59346 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=1140262999 TSecr=1623858684 WS=64
161 88.205022   192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 72  [TCP Dup ACK 139#4] 59346 → 80 [ACK] Seq=124 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1623859335 TSecr=1140247999
167 101.623755  192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 195 [TCP Retransmission] 59346 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=123 TSval=1623872754 TSecr=1140247999
189 104.244772  142.250.200.46  192.168.1.192   TCP 80  [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 59346 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM TSval=1140278999 TSecr=1623872754 WS=64
190 104.244831  192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 72  [TCP Dup ACK 139#5] 59346 → 80 [ACK] Seq=124 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1623875375 TSecr=1140247999
204 129.143750  192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 195 [TCP Retransmission] 59346 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=123 TSval=1623900274 TSecr=1140247999
211 165.074469  192.168.1.192   142.250.200.46  TCP 72  59346 → 80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=124 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1623936204 TSecr=1140247999
212 165.075820  142.250.200.46  192.168.1.192   TCP 66  80 → 59346 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

Comment: What is the pi being used for?  Are there any iptables rules gettimg in the way? (try "iptables -vnL" to list.

Comment: @davidgo right now, nothing. It's a completely fresh raspbian install. `iptables -vnL` Just shows 
"
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
" (sorry for the formatting)

Comment: Your hypothesis its the router seems reasonable.  You can bolster it by  doing a tcpdump and seeing what is being sent and received. (In 1 window run "tcpdump -i any pport not 22" then doing a curl/wget request in the other).  This will show what is lraving and coming back to tje box (other then ssh traffic)

Comment: @davidgo updated the post to include this. This has left me even more confused. Seems that google is refusing to complete the TCP process with the rpi... Again, this works with a proxy and with https.

Comment: Its not that Google is refusing the tcp process - Line 4 shows its established. Its the retries on line 5- that are the problem.  No idea whats going on there though. I keep coming back to a transparent proxy fiddling with packets in a way your Pi does not like - but have 0 evidence to support this hypothesis.

Comment: Thought - if connected to another network does your Pi still behave like this?

Comment: Also, are you able to spin up a web server on your LAN and see if your Pi likes that? That could help narrow where the network issues are.

Comment: @davidgo If I spin up a http server via `python3 -m http.server` and ` curl 192.168.1.19:8000/test.txt` where `test.txt` was created by me, it was all completely fine...

Comment: I sadly don't have access to another network but I'll try bridging my desktop or something...

Comment: You may want to try seeing if the problem is isolated to port 80.

Answer (score -1):

Glad it's not me that is receiving issues with the Vodafone routers, they are properly bad!

I have had issues with the DHCP side of things on the ISP's router and had to reset about 2 weeks ago. This weekend it happened again so I popped to Argos and picked up a TP-Link router/modem... more functionality and at least allows you to access default ssh port 22 (blocked by Vodafone's router - why???). Seems and already feels 10x better - I use Unifi Lite 6 as a mesh Wi-Fi system on a flat 1gb Cable network.

You will need to request the PPPOE information from them which can be done via their online chat.

To mention, I have an Orange Pi (Mysterium Node) and Raspberry pi running Unifi Controller (Couldn't get DHCP to work for the life of me) and had no issues until the DHCP issue on the Vodafone router.

I think the Vodafone router are probably fine if left on default setting but anything other than that I don't think they have the power to cope.

Sorry if this wasn't helpful in anyway.

Comment: Good to know I can buy a 3rd party router. I'm starting to lose my cool with this piece of rubbish...

Comment: Just researching your router, it would appear your router is newer than mine, but I can't believe it will be much better. You have a black fibre box on the wall that then links to your router? I have copper to the house but Fibre to the street so still essentially ADSL but ADSLV (I think!).

Your router choice should be much bigger than mine though!

Comment: As far as I know, mine is DSL. We went for the cheapest broadband option which is probably why it's DSL. Should be easy enough to replace if that becomes the only solution.